# Troubles with a C# function and SqlCommand that execute a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is my first post here. I really like this place, I've found a lot of interesting stuff so far, so I decided to get aboard!

I'm experiencing something weird trying to use a recursive call in C#. This is what I'm doing.

```
//routine for downloading Phases
public static int DownloadPhases(string competitionId, string competitionCountry, string competitionPhase = "")
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    DateTime phaseStart = DateTime.Now, phaseEnd = DateTime.Now, outDate;

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    bool isDate = false, isNumeric = false;

    string url = "", phaseId = "", phaseCode = "", phaseName = "", phaseDesc = "";
    int phaseSort = 0, outNum = 0, result = 0;

    // load structure for inserting new Phases
    SqlUtilities.sqlLoadDt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sqlSel_insCompetitionsPhase"], ref dt);

    DataColumn[] keyColumn2 = new DataColumn[3];
    keyColumn2[0] = dt.Columns["phase_ID"];
    keyColumn2[1] = dt.Columns["phase_Competition"];
    keyColumn2[2] = dt.Columns["phase_Country"];

    dt.PrimaryKey = keyColumn2;

    try
    {
        if (competitionPhase == "")
            url = buildUrl("15", "", "", competitionCountry, competitionId);
        else
            url = buildUrl("15", "", "", competitionCountry, competitionPhase);

        loadXml(xmlDoc, url);

        // set a nodelist with all the &lt;category&gt; tags for Phases
        XmlNodeList competitions = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Item");

        // for each node in the the nodelist, get all the infos about it
        foreach (XmlNode competition in competitions)
        {
            //phase
            phaseId = competition.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value.ToString();
            phaseCode = competition.Attributes.GetNamedItem("code").Value.ToString();
            phaseName = competition.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value.ToString();
            phaseDesc = competition.Attributes.GetNamedItem("description").Value.ToString();

            isDate = DateTime.TryParse(competition.Attributes.GetNamedItem("comp_start").Value.ToString(), out outDate);

            if (isDate == true) 
                phaseStart = outDate;

            isDate = DateTime.TryParse(competition.Attributes.GetNamedItem("comp_end").Value.ToString(), out outDate);

            if (isDate == true) 
               phaseEnd = outDate;

            isNumeric = int.TryParse(competition.Attributes.GetNamedItem("sort").Value.ToString(), out outNum);

            if (isNumeric == true) 
               phaseSort = outNum;

            // adding competition to datatable dt
            if (phaseId != "")
            {
               try
               {
                   dt.Rows.Add(phaseId, competitionId, competitionCountry, phaseCode, phaseStart, phaseEnd, phaseDesc, phaseName, phaseSort);
                   result += 1;

                   if (phaseDesc.Contains("NOT LEAF"))
                      <b>DlData.DownloadPhases(competitionId, competitionCountry, phaseId);</b>
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                    ex.Message.ToString();
               }
               finally
               {
                    phaseId = "";
               }
           }
        } //end foreach phase
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         ex.Message.ToString();
     }
     finally
     {
          //call stored procedure to insert Phases
          SqlUtilities.sqlExecuteSp("dbo.usp_insCompetitionsPhase", dt);
     }

     return result;
}
```

And this is the `SqlExecuteSp` function

```
public static void sqlExecuteSp(string cmdText, DataTable parDt)
{
  try
  {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
    SqlTransaction trans;

    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FTBLConnectionStringSuperUser"].ConnectionString;

    conn.Open();

    using (conn)
    {
      trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
      comm.CommandText = cmdText;
      comm.Connection = conn;
      comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      comm.Transaction = trans;

      param = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", parDt);
      param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

      comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

      trans.Commit();
    }

    conn.Close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ex.Message.ToString();
  }
}
```

When I try to call the `SqlExecuteSp` function recursively, it seems to execute it correctly, but I can't see the new rows inserted till when I delete the first ones.

So, If I run `delete from tbl_competition_phases` in SQL Server Management Studio, it only deletes the "old" rows, and from now on I can see the rows inserted with the second call.

I thought this happened due to an incomplete transaction so, as you can see, I added a transaction object, without results.

I know that recursive calls in c# are not the best thing to do. Anyway, in this case I'm quite sure that there won't be more than 2 calls, so I think it won't be a problem.

Any suggest?

Thank you very much!

Damiano

Comment: You are swallowing your exceptions which could be hiding any errors - remove the pointless catch blocks and see if you get the same behaviour. If you do could you show the SQL in the stored proc you are calling?

Comment: Sorry ajg, what do you mean with "swallowing your exceptions"? And why should those catch blocks be the origin of the evil?

Comment: I'm not saying they are definitely the origin of the problem - but they could be masking what the error is. By having a catch block - but not doing anything with the error your code ignores any error and just carries on to the next run. Try removing them and come back and let me know if the behaviour changes.

Comment: He means you're calling ex.Message.ToString(), but not actually logging or displaying the message anywhere. Which is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've spotted what the error could be - in the sqlExecuteSp method you have your conn in a using block (which is declared incorrectly) - but are calling close outside of it after it has been disposed. This will be causing an exception. As I said in the comments - the fact you are swallowing exceptions is hiding this from you.

Try this for the sqlExecuteSp method

```
public static void sqlExecuteSp(string cmdText, DataTable parDt)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())                    
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FTBLConnectionStringSuperUser"].ConnectionString;
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                comm.Connection = conn;
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comm.Transaction = trans;

                SqlParameter param = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", parDt);
                param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                trans.Commit();
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

this may not be the cause of the behaviour you are seeing - but would certainly cause an error / unexpected behaviour when the program runs.

A few tips

- enclose objects that can be disposed in using blocks to ensure they
  are disposed even if an error occurred (e.g. if your connection string
  was missing from the config file) and use the correct way of doing this as shown in my example
- Reduce the scope of your variables (only declare them when needed) - reduces the amount of time they have to exist and makes the code more readable (e.g. i moved the SqlParameter declaration down to only where its needed)
- Don't bother using try catch finally unless its part of a wider exception handling framework - or maybe only if you are wanting to log the exceptions  and if you are logging rethrow so the error bubbles up. By using it where its not needed you are hiding errors which would have helped you to diagnose the problem. Sometimes its worth using try / finally alone to ensure a bit of code gets run - notice you don't have to have the catch block. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722964/when-to-use-try-catch-blocks) question has some useful reading on this

Comment: Thanks ajg for your help. I was debugging the code row by row and I'm sure that no exception was thrown while running. While debugging, I only needed to know what the exception was like, so an ex.message.toString() was enough. Anyway, I've tried to change the sqlExecuteSp procedure following your suggestion, but unfortunatly nothing changed. It's really weird.. Thx again

Comment: Anyway, I've solved the problem by changing the logic. I prepare the datatable, recursively if necessary, and doing so I can call the stored procedure only once. This works perfectly.